# PHP Page does not load data till I refresh after form submit

Tags: php

I have a main php Admin page that allows me to edit information contained within my database.  I have several forms on the page, and a tabbed setup that allows me to nest the edit forms within each tab.  All the forms refer Action="" back to the same php page for process and the page naturally looks to see if a button isset after POSTing otherwise just loads the usual tables and does not UPDATE the database.

Prior to web deployment I utilise XAMPP to develop the pages, however, once contented with the pages I upload to HostPapa.  Whilst in the XAMPP environment, when i submit my information to be processed the page loads fine, the database is UPDATEd and the Success Message displays fine.  However, once I upload to HostPapa and attempt the same steps, once i click the submit button and the data is sent back to the same page for processing, only a blank screen appears.  When i hit refresh though it completes the processing and displays the Success Message.  Data is UPDATEd in the database and nothing else appears to be wrong.

My questions are:

- Any idea why my localhost website would display fine but my live version kind of stutters through the processing
- Is this a setting on HostPapa that may need changing
- Have i fallen pray to a coding taboo that prompts this response in the live environment

Worth noting that I had another XAMPP/HostPapa issue where I had not utilised the correct file name with Capitals in a form and this caused a failure as the file name did not match the coded file name exactly.  This was rectified by insuring that file names and coded file name were match and case sensitive.  The local XAMPP server did not care about case sensitivity which makes be believe that the form submission issue noted above may be a PHP option on HostPapa that is currently turn one.

Any assistance in this matter would be appreciated.

Regards,

C

Comment: Sometimes when you work on localhost, everything is so fast that you can not see problems that appears when you work online, especially asynchronous functions for example. Please try to [simulate a slow internet connection](https://dandkim.com/simulate-slow-networks/test%20slow%20network%20connections/) with the browser developer tools on your localhost version, and tell us if this still works with the slow connection

Comment: Hi Dony, I gave it a go with 3G speed and a Custom 50kb/s and the page still loads without issue.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who reads this and had a similar issue when utilising multiple forms on the same page.  My issue is I had breaks(empty rows) between my `<?php ?>` tags in the header of the document.

I used several `<?php ?>` tags to encompass the different `$_POST` functions for my own clarity.   This caused the server to interpret these breaks(empty rows) as an intentional space and made it appear that the header had already been sent.  So naturally as my page attempted to load, the server believed i was attempting modify the header that had already been sent.

I believe this coding faux pas was masked by XAMPP during my offline build.  I did a bit more research and I believe this also has something to do with the UTC selection.

At any rate, thank you Dony for attempting to assist.  It was a hard issue to articulate.

Regards,

Cheyne